# Combinatorics Ramsey Theory Proof

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

There are 9 passengers on a bus, some know each other. Among
every 3 passengers there are two who know each other. Prove that there are at
least 5 passengers, each of which knows at least 4 people on the bus.

Comment: You can prove something a little stronger: either **every** passenger knows at least $4$ people on the bus, or else there are $5$ passengers who all know one another.

Comment: How does the requirement that among every 3 passengers, there are 2 who know each other affect your solution?

Comment: If some passenger knows at most $3$ other passengers, then there are $5$ passengers that he does not know. In that case, those $5$ people must all know one another; otherwise, there would be $3$ people, no two of whom know each other.

Comment: Do you know of a way to prove this using ramsey theory? I understand the premise but am having a hard time discovering a proper proof.

Comment: What's wrong with the proof I described in my previous comment?

Comment: Nothing at all. I guess I was just expecting something less concise and involving edge coloring. Thank you!